# Wordpress 6.2.2: unable to get fontawesome (or even a svg) to work in add to cart button

Tags: php, wordpress, function, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I'm using the following to display fontawesome in the add to cart button,

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_single_add_to_cart_text', 'custom_add_to_cart_button_text_single' );
function custom_add_to_cart_button_text_single( $button_text ) {
    $button_text = '<i class="fa fa-shopping-cart" aria-hidden="true"></i> Add to Cart';
    return $button_text;
}
```

how ever the `<i class="fa fa-shopping-cart" aria-hidden="true"></i>` displays as text as follows,

```
&lt;i class="fa fa-shopping-cart" aria-hidden="true"&gt;&lt;/i&gt;
```

I have fontawesome installed and when I edit the html using browser inspect and change

```
&lt;i class="fa fa-shopping-cart" aria-hidden="true"&gt;&lt;/i&gt;
```

to

```
<i class="fa fa-shopping-cart" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

it displays.

I'm not sure what I need to do to get the code to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the functions that have the `woocommerce_product_single_add_to_cart_text` filter are used by WooCommerce's templates, and use [`esc_html()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/esc_html/) to prevent HTML from displaying (ex: [`single-product/add-to-cart/simple.php`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/trunk/plugins/woocommerce/templates/single-product/add-to-cart/simple.php)).

The better approach is to [override WooCommerce templates in your theme](https://woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/), and change the button to not use the function, and instead use your Font Awesome icon.

Comment: so I copy this file yourtheme/woocommerce/single-product/add-to-cart/simple.php into the theme child folder maintaining the same folder structure and then add in the <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart" aria-hidden="true"></i>, is that correct?

Comment: You'll need to position the code for the icon inside of the `<button>` tags, but otherwise, yes, this is correct.

Comment: Thanks boet, that worked, so anytime I want to make changes I adopt this approach, just copy template file into the child theme and make changes?

Comment: If you can make the change using filters or actions, then you should, but if not, overriding the template is the next option.

Comment: and by filters and actions you mean changes via the functions file correct?

Comment: Yes: `add_action()` or `add_filter()`.